# Non-minimally coupled inflation

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, gravity, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

In Wikipedia you can read under the Keyword Inflaton , the Formula:
What do the individual formula symbols mean in the following formula:

$$S=\int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \left[\frac{1}{2}m^2_{P}R-\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\Phi\partial_{ \mu }\Phi-V(\Phi)-\frac{ 1 }{ 2}\xi R \Phi^2\right]$$

What is $d^{4}x$?
What is $g$ ? What is $m^2_{P}$? What is $R$? And $\phi^\mu$? And $\Phi_\mu$? And $\Phi$? And $V(\Phi)$? And $\xi$?

Is $d^4x$ the volume integral? $g=$ metric tensor?
$m^2_{P}=$Planck mass? $\Phi=$scalar field? $V(\Phi)=$ potential energy of the scalar field? $\xi=$ coupling constant? $R=$ Ricci scalar?
What is $\partial^\mu$? And $\partial_\mu$?

best regards
Mark

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the second term is actually $$-\frac12\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi=-\frac12g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\Phi\partial_\nu\Phi\tag{1},$$

and $\partial_\mu\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ means partial derivative with respect to the coordinate $x^\mu$.

> What is $g$?

It is the determinant of the metric tensor, whose components are $g_{\mu\nu}$ (when the indices are up as in $(1)$, it means the components of the inverse of the metric)

> What is $d^4x$?

Together with $\sqrt{-g}$, i.e. $d^4x\sqrt{-g}$, it is the [volume element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element#Volume_element_of_manifolds.) in four dimensions.

> What is $m_P^2$?

It is the Planck mass (squared) as you say.

> What is $R$? And $\Phi$? And $V(\Phi)$? And $\xi$?

Your guesses are correct.

Comment: What is $\partial^\mu\Phi\partial_{ \mu }\Phi$ is there the d'Alembert operator important ?